# Extending JS object instance using lodash's extend method causes weird results

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I've have a JS class that has some default properties. I want to be able to pass in an options object to override the defaults plus some additional ones that aren't defaulted. I'm using lodash's `extend` method in my constructor to accomplish this.

One of the default properties is an array. If I instantiate the first instance and push a new value into the array, when I instantiate the second object, the default array contains the object I pushed into the first instance.

Take this code for example...

```
MyClass = (function() {
  var defaults = {
    myArr: [],
    myProp: 'I\'m a default value'
  };

  function MyClass(options) {
    // console.log(defaults)
    if(typeof options === 'object') {
      return _.extend(this, defaults, options);
    }
    else {
      return _.extend(this, defaults);
    }
  }

  return MyClass;
})();

var myObj = new MyClass({foo: 'bar'})
myObj.myArr.push('baz')
var mySecondObj = new MyClass();
console.log(mySecondObj) // MyClass {myArr: Array[1]}
```

I expect `mySecondObj.myArr` to be an empty array.

How is it that when I push a value into `myObj.myArr`, `defaults.myArr` somehow gets changed and is used for subsequent instances of the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you merge the object properties from `defaults` to `this` with `_.extend` you're merely creating a reference to the array. So when the array reference in one instance is updated, all the the references reflect that change.

You could clone the object to get around this:

```
_.cloneDeep(defaults)
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wydyeoju/3/)

Or use a simpler constructor:

```
function MyClass(options) {
  var defaults = {
    myArr: [],
    myProp: 'I\'m a default value'
  }
  if (typeof options === 'object') {
    _.extend(this, defaults, options);
  } else {
    _.extend(this, defaults);
  }
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wydyeoju/1/)

Comment: Thanks everyone. This, in addition to the comment regarding the closure makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Simple put: You created a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1).

Inside your self-executing function you create another function, the function you created inherit `defaults` from it's parent-self-executing function, when you return the function to `MyClass` any object creation will have the same reference for those defaults(`the defaults object`), there is no `defaults` object created each time you create a class and that is why it's always the same one.